# UIViewController child view controller accessibility

Tags: ios, ipad, accessibility, fullscreen, uiaccessibility

While adding a child view controller, is there a way to hide parent VC elements from the voiceover access?

I've a parent view controller P, which adds a child view controller C as a full screen page view controller. Once the transition to the full screen finishes, the voiceover still goes through the elements in the parent view controller.

Any idea how I can hide/disable accessibility of elements in the parent view controller?

Answer (score 3):

You can set [accessibilityViewIsModal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615089-accessibilityviewismodal) on the occluding view. Note that the view is made modal relative to sibling views, not globally. If you need to hide views in parallel view hierarchies from the accessibility hierarchy, consider toggling [accessibilityElementsHidden](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615080-accessibilityelementshidden).